# Where is the parameter 'request' used in view.py in django

Tags: python, django, httprequest, render, httpresponse

A newbie in Django web development. I've got a tiny but puzzling question about request / response in views.py.

1. I self-learn Django online and here comes the http request / response section. The code is as follows:

```
#from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>123</h1>")
```

I understand that the index page is requested and django creates a response which shows 123 in the index page. My questions are:

1. with the `request` as the parameter of the function, isn't it used in the body of the function, just like `def math(x): return x+1`?
2. Also, why does `render` become redundant in this trunk of code, where it should be used to produce output?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Render is used on templates, it takes a request object to be passed onto the templates. Render returns an HTTPResponse which will then be written to the client connection. Have a look at the following resources, they might provide more insight. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response

Comment: 1. request is just a httprequest object and you are not passing any parameters or body so in this code the request object is not being used. You are just sending a static html response for the request received.

2. render is a specialized form in which you are going to send your response object based on requested context using some form of template. Like the code "<h1>123</h1>" goes into a template file and is loaded and sent as response.

Answer (score 2):

1. `request` object is passed as a parameter but you don't use it in the function body. You can - if you want to access some information from your incoming request. Let's say user pass a number "2023" and you capture it using `request.get` etc.
2. `render` function is used to render an HTML template and pass contextual data to that template. From Django doc

> Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns
> an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.
>
> Django does not provide a shortcut function which returns a
> TemplateResponse because the constructor of TemplateResponse offers
> the same level of convenience as render().

Now you didn't use `render` in your code so it is an unused import and probably a linter suggested you to comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. with the `request` as the parameter of the function, isn't it used in the body of the function, just like `def math(x): return x+1`?

Here indeed the request is not used. But this is a "boring" view: usually views process data. For example if a user fills in a form, the data filled in is accessible in `request.POST` if it is a POST request, or `request.GET` to process the querystring of the URL. Middleware also attaches items to the request like `request.user` to get the logged in user, or the session variables.

Django will always call the view function with the request as first parameter, and URL parameters as kwargs. One can also specify additional values for parameters in the [**`path`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urls/#django.urls.path). This thus means that even if you *don't* use the parameter, you need to specify it, otherwise there will be a mismatch with caller and the callee.

> 2. Also, why does render become redundant in this trunk of code, where it should be used to produce output?

You again don't use the render function. [**`render(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) is used to render a template and wrap the result in a `HttpResponse`, so a common pattern is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app_name/some_template.html')
```

this will then render a template, that is, depending on the settings, probably stored in `'<i>app_name</i>/templates/<i>app_name</i>/<i>some_template.html</i>'`. This is thus a function that is used to make writing views more convenient.